# How to exclude a specific instance from a nested serializer, but include it in the underling model

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Is there a way to exclude a specific instance from a nested serializer, but include it in the underlying model?

Consider the following code:

**models.py**

```
class Author(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class Book(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  authors = models.ForeignKey(Author, related_name="books")
```

**serializers.py**

```
class BookSerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = Book
    fields = ["title"]

class AuthorSerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = Author
    fields = ["name",  "books"]

  books = BookSerializer(many=True)

  def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    books_validated_data = validated_data.pop("books")
    author = self.update(instance, validated_data)
    for book_validated_data in books_validated_data:
      # this might not be valid code, but you get the idea
      Book.objects.update_or_create(author=author, **book_validated_data)  
    return author
```

Now, suppose that every author must have the book "Hamlet".  But, I don't want to include that book in the serializer output or input.

```
>> shakespeare = Author(name="Shakespeare").save()
>> hamlet = Book(author=shakespeare, title="Hamlet").save()
>> othello = Book(author=shakespeare, title="Othello").save()
```

When I serialize that I ought to return something like:

```
{  
  "name": "Shakespeare",
  "books": [{"title": "Othello"}]   
}
```

Notice that "Hamlet" is not there.  But when I POST something like this to the serializer:

```
{  
  "name": "Shakespeare",
  "books": [{"title": "Othello"}, {"title": "King Lear"}]
}
```

I don't want the code to wind up removing the existing "Hamlet" (even though it's not specified in the JSON above).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very happy w/ this solution.  But overriding `to_internal_value` and `to_representation` seems to work:

```
   def to_internal_value(self, data):
        hamlet_books = self.instance.books.filter(title="Hamlet")
        data["books"] += BookSerializer(hamlet_books, many=True).data
        return super().to_internal_value(data)

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        representation = super().to_representation(instance)
        books_representation = representation.pop("books", [])
        hamlet_books = instance.books.filter(title="Hamlet")
        representation["books"] = filterfalse(
            lambda x: x["id"] in hamlet_books.values_list("id", flat=True),
            books_representation,
        )
        return representation
```